# BufferedReader Null Deference

Tags: java, xss, stringbuffer, notnull

Here at the line `while((anInt=bufferedReader.read())!=-1)` iam getting `Null Dereference` issue when i do my XSS validation on the below code. For this is this enough to check not null or do we have any other check or solution to resolve this..

```
BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
    try {
        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File (url.toURI())));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    response.setContentType("text/plain");
    try{
        int anInt=0;
        //if(!bufferedReader.equals(null)){
            while((anInt=bufferedReader.read())!=-1)
                response.getWriter().write(anInt);
        //}
    } catch(IOException ioe) { }
    return null;
```

Commented the if condition..

Comment: This Question doesn't make a lot of sense to me.  Are you talking about a NullPointerException?  If so, please add the stacktrace to the Question.

Comment: `BufferedReader.readLine()` returns **null** when it has finished to read.

Comment: @AsierAranbarri As he isn't calling `readLine(),` your comment has zero relevance.

Comment: @EJP it hasn't zero relevance. Now I'm aware of my mistake, so it was useful for me to put that comment here. ; )

Comment: @AsierAranbarri It has zero relevance to the question being asked, which is what comments are supposed to be about. It's nice that you learned something from me that you could have learned by reading the question more carefully but again it isn't relevant to the actual question.

Answer (score 3):

> I am getting `Null Dereference` issue

No you're not. There is no such 'issue'. What you're getting is a `NullPointerException.` Please be accurate. There is no virtue whatsoever in paraphrasing error messages, or not reading them properly, or whatever it was that led to this error on your part.

The *ostensible* error here is using `bufferedReader.equals()` as a test to see whether `bufferedReader` is `null.` A moment's thought should convince you of the futility of doing it that way. If it's null, how is calling `equals()` on it ever going to succeed?

The *original* error on your part here was poorly structured exception handling. You have code after the `catch` block that relies on the success of the `try` block. It should therefore be *inside* the `try` block. You will then notice that you only need one `catch` block ... but please put something inside it, such as `exc.printStackTrace():` otherwise debugging becomes a mere guessing game.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the bad exception handling pointed out by EJP (and your egregious paraphrasing ...), your code always returns `null`.  That seems kind of pointless.

---

But the real problem is actually *caused* by your bad exception handling.

First this:

```
BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
try {
    bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
            new FileReader(new File (url.toURI())));
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

If the file open fails, you catch the exception AND CONTINUE.  That is your first mistake.  You should NOT catch the exception there, because you are not ready to handle it there.

Next this:

```
if (!bufferedReader.equals(null)) {
```

I expect this is *supposed* to guard against `bufferedReader` being `null`.  But in reality, if `bufferedReader` is `null`, then the will *cause* an NPE to be thrown ... because you will be trying to call a method (`equals`) on a null target object.

If you want to test if `bufferedReader` is `null`, you should code it like this:

```
if (bufferedReader != null) {
```

But you wouldn't *need* to test for `null` at all if you hadn't tried to handle the previous exception at that point ...

---

> ok. i am removing that .equals condition

Sigh.  Stop hacking the code and *try to **understand** the Answers*.

Removing the test without fixing the first problem is just *moving* the place where an NPE is going to be thrown.

Comment: Okay.. i will write the null check as you mentioned.

Comment: @Mdhar9e - You are STILL not reading the Answers properly.  If you fix the FIRST problem and you don't need to test for a null at all.

Answer (score 0):

`bufferedReader.equals(null)` should throw a `NullPointerException` to check `bufferedReader`is null or not you can do  `bufferedReader != null`.

Comment: Only if `bufferedReader` is null.

Comment: Of course, if bufferedReader is not null No NullPointerException should throw.

Comment: For clarity, if `bufferedReader` is null, `bufferedReader.equals()` will throw a `NullPointerException.` If it isn't null, it won't, and indeed even calling it is pointless if you've already tested it for `!= null.`

Answer (score -1):

bufferedReader may throw EoFException you must handle it!

Comment: There are no methods of `BufferedReader` that throw `EOFException.` All the `read()` overloads return -1 at EOS, and `readLine()` returns `null.` -1